# Game server rewrite player files with newvalue

Tags: php

I have players files from my game server but i want this files rewrite with php.
But i want rewrite specific line and part of the line. I have code for search the line but i dont know ho this line rewrite.

```
$file = fopen( "file.txt" , "r" );

if( $file ) {
    while( ($line = fgets($file)) !== false ) 
    {
         if( strpos( $line , "key" ) !== false )
         {
             $value = explode("=",$line)[1];
             $newvalue = $value+100;
         }
    }
}
```

The file looks like this:

```
key = value
```

How i rewrite this value to newvalue?

Comment: You have to write all the old lines, and you new changed line back to the file ... Use `file` instead of fopen, then you have an array with the lines. Find the right one, modify it ... and then `implode` the whole array back into a single string with a line break as join character, and write it back to the file using file_put_contents.

Comment: If you can change the file format. I suggest you use a well known format, that makes your life and code maintainablility a lot easier. For example the file formats JSON, INI, YAML or whatever you like to save simple text based data.